# Write a test that clicks on views inside PopupWindow

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a ListView inside a PopupWindow, and I want to click on the second item on the list. I've tried the following:

```
// Open the popupwindow
onView(withId(R.id.popupwindow_open)).perform(click());
```

And now that the popup window appears, I tried:

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withContentDescription("delete")).atPosition(1).perform(
        click());
```

or this:

```
onView(withContentDescription("delete"))).perform(click());
```

But I always get that the view isn't found. How can I do this in Espresso?

Comment: Espresso should be able to find views in `PopupWindow`s. Are you sure your view has content description of "delete"? You're not confusing `android:text` with `android:contentDescription`?

Comment: `.inAdapterView(withContentDescription("delete"))` means that the ListView itself must have a contentDescription of "delete". Does removing the inAdapterView work? i.e. `onData(anything()).atPosition(1).perform(
        click());` Also, if you post the full error message, it will help us better understand the problem.

Answer (score 41):

The Android System Popups and Alerts are displayed in a different window. So, you have to try to find the view in that particular window rather than the main activity window.

Espresso provides a convenient method to find the root view for popup windows. Try this.

```
onView(ViewMatchers.withContentDescription("delete"))
         .inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup())
         .perform(ViewActions.click());
```

Comment: you are a life saver, after hours trying all solutions, I wish this had more votes: for me it worked with text search  onView(withText("Popup Selection 1"))
                .inRoot(isPlatformPopup())
                .perform(click());

Comment: This and Miheala's comment helped tremendously. This worked for me: onView(withText("Okay")).inRoot(RootMatchers.isPlatformPopup()).perform(click())

Comment: Same here withText worked, content description also gave me no matching view found. Thanks to Mihaela and Nishanth, perhaps there is an opportunity to improve the original answer.

Answer (score 5):

In your case you have two different windows. So, to point to Espresso which window you want to interact with, you have to use Root matcher. Try out or play with these solutions a bit:

```
onView(withContentDescription("delete"))
    .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
    .perform(click());
```

or

```
onData(withContentDescription("delete"))
    .inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView()))))
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.adapter_view))
    .perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onView(withId(android.R.id.id_you_are_looking_for)).perform(click());
```

In my case, I use system dialogs, so id has to be preceded with "android", then it works fine